# AWS Elastic Beanstak and Custom Environment Variables

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, fuelphp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been looking but I'm not sure I have found an adequate answer for this.

I would like to set a unique environment variable for each Environment I have in my application.

When I create my application I will have two environments: staging and production.

In the first one I want to set a custom environment variable called FUEL_ENV (this is for the framework that I use: FuelPHP) it will have the value "staging". For the second environment, FUEL_ENV will be set to "production".

Technically I can create a custom variable by using configuration files like this:

```
  option_settings:
  - option_name: FUEL_ENV
    value: staging
```

This doesn't solve my problem unless there is a way to set variables for on each environment.

What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This part isn't very clear in the docs.  The option_settings are great for setting up stuff that is general to your application but not environment specific.

Two thoughts:

- I have been wondering if there is a mechanism in the
  option-settings. files (if you are using the
  command line tools) that would allow **flexible** configuration for each environment.
- It is more rigid than I think you want but there are the available
  PARAM1...5 parameters that are environment specific and can be set
  through the web-based EB console or through the optionsettings files.

You can use the second bullet I think because you only have need for 1 item to be injected into your application to determine what FUEL_ENV will be in that EB environment.  The PARAM1, PARAM2 ... values are injected into PHP's $_SERVER super global so your app can pick them up there like this:

FUEL_ENV = $_SERVER['PARAM1'];